# Animating swipe actions in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, tableview, ios9

I want to animate tableview row actions like the mail app . I don't like to use third party libraries .I want to try on my own .And how to add the full swipe functionality like mail app ?

For sample gif please visit this link

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerkoch/SwipeCellKit/develop/Screenshots/Hero.gif

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions like these are [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try asking [minimal specific questions about programming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), by splitting your problem into smaller questions. If you require tutorials and courses on how to accomplish your goals, unfortunately Stack Overflow is not the right place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get answer from the third party libraries. Simply like this:

1. Add a pangesture on cell
2. Add buttons you want
3. When you begin swiping on cell, create a same image with cell
4. Create a imageview with the image and add it to the cell
5. When you swipe, move the imageview

Comment: Thanks ,am currently trying to do this but its not interactive as the iOS mail app i want to make it more fluid and i wan to support the iOS 8+

Comment: just a doubt why is that not possible to achieve the same with tableViewRowActions .why its not animated